# Variable precision arithmetic for definite integrals in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration, arbitrary-precision

I want to evaluate a definite integral with variable precision arithmetic in Matlab. It can be done using symbolic math toolbox in this way:

```
syms x
f = (x.^2000).*((1-x).^4000) 
vpa(int(f,0,1))
```

This gives me the answer of the integral with variable precision arithmetic.

But I like to evaluate the integral without symbolic math toolbox. I can use the command 'integral' to calculate the integral but since the integral is calculated in fixed precision, it returns zero, i.e. the output of the following code is zero.

```
f = @(x) (x.^2000).*((1-x).^4000)
integral(f,0,1)
```

How can I combine vpa with numerical integration without using symbolic math toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

Impossible, because the [vpa function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) is a part of the symbolic math toolbox. If you are using vpa, you are using this toolbox.